# Iterating a json array in postgresesql and filtering based on data

Tags: postgresql

```json
[{“name”=“abc”,”type”=“charts”},{“name”=“def”,”type”=“transactions”}]
```

Attachment column gives me this data but I need to iterate this and check if type is present and if type=charts or transactions ..mainly we need to filter it out .can someone help me on this as I am new to Postgres

Comment: What data type is the column `attachment`?  That is not a valid JSON value.

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear to me what exactly you want to filter.

If you just want to see rows that contain a specific type, you can use:

```
select *
from the_table
where attachment @> '[{"type": "transactions"}]';
```

This will return all rows that include at least one element with `{"type": "transactions"}` in the array.

This assumes that your `attachment` column is defined as `jsonb`. If it's not you will need to cast it.